# The following artifacts could not be resolved: external.gearman.service:gearman:jar:0.6.6

Tags: java, maven, artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-mission-control

I am using JFrog Artifactory with settings.xml as

> ```
> https://pastebin.com/thKdzie3
> ```

I am building a jar of a project with pom.xml file as

> ```
> https://pastebin.com/0QndKK8H
> ```

I run "mvn clean install" and face the following error.

```
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project scrybe_cronjobs: Could not
> resolve dependencies for project
> com.abc:scrybe_cronjobs:jar:PHP7-1.0: The following artifacts could
> not be resolved: external.gearman.service:gearman:jar:0.6.6,
> external.smack:smack-core:jar:0.1, external.apns:apns:jar:1.0: Failure
> to find external.gearman.service:gearman:jar:0.6.6 in
> http://maven-repo.abc.net:8081/artifactory/libs-release was
> cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
> until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
> -> [Help 1] [ERROR]
```

How can I fix this issue? Might be external jars are not being download. Please guide.

Comment: Please add the `settings.xml` and POM as text to the question.

Answer (score 0):

if dependencies are correctly in repo, you can try -U option to force update

from mvn --help

```
-U,--update-snapshots               Forces a check for missing
                                    releases and updated snapshots on
                                    remote repositories
```

Comment: Lets talk about gearman. It is not in my internal jfrog artifactory. When I do "mvn clean install", it will check from internal private repo like "http://maven-repo.abc.net:8081/artifactory/libs-release". If it is not here as it is not. Then it should not download from public maven repo and then server my project. May be there is some problem in my understanding. Please go through my settings.xml and pom.xml, are they fine?